# How do I upload photos to Instagram with python since Instagram shutdown its API service

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

How do I upload photos to Instagram with python and selenium without Instagram API

Comment: there are alternatives ... (eg https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium (specifically Chromedriver) in mobile emulation mode to upload photos. Here's a good example: https://github.com/atloftus/IGF
specifically look at the uploadPhoto method. Hope this helps